# Java Regex - Remove Non-Alphanumeric characters except line breaks

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove all the non-alphanumeric characters from a String in Java but keep the carriage returns. I have the following regular expression, but it keeps joining words before and after a line break.

```
[^\\p{Alnum}\\s]
```

How would I be able to preserve the line breaks or convert them into spaces so that I don't have words joining?

An example of this issue is shown below:

Original Text

```
and refreshingly direct
when compared with the hand-waving of Swinburne.
```

After Replacement:

```
 and refreshingly directwhen compared with the hand-waving of Swinburne.
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"it keeps joining words before and after a line break"*? That regex will retain all spaces and linebreaks, so it won't "join words". Please edit question and show example of what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You may add these chars to the regex, not `\s`, as `\s` matches any whitespace:

```
String reg = "[^\\p{Alnum}\n\r]";
```

Or, you may use [*character class  subtraction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

```
String reg = "[\\P{Alnum}&&[^\n\r]]";
```

Here, `\P{Alnum}` matches any non-alphanumeric and `&&[^\n\r]` prevents a LF and CR from matching.

A [Java test](http://ideone.com/L5ejpb):

```
String s = "&&& Text\r\nNew line".replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}\n\r]+", "");
System.out.println(s); 
// => Text
Newline
```

Note that there are more line break chars than LF and CR. In Java 8, `\R` construct matches any style linebreak and [it matches `\u000D\u000A|\[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029\]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

So, to exclude matching any line breaks, you may use

```
String reg = "[^\\p{Alnum}\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]+";
```

Comment: `\r` and `\n` don't have to be double escaped since Java strings support escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `[^A-Za-z0-9\\n\\r]` for example :

```
String result = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\n\\r]", "");
```

**Example**

**Input**

```
aaze03.aze1654aze987  */-a*azeaze\n hello *-*/zeaze+64\nqsdoi
```

**Output**

```
aaze03aze1654aze987aazeaze
hellozeaze64
qsdoi
```

Comment: alphanumeric is more than [A-Za-z0-9]; at least in non english languages (äöüéèñ ...), so you will be removing too much

Comment: @P.J.Meisch: However, OP `\p{Alnum}` does deal with ASCII only. Unless the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is used, this is quite the same. However, only a newline is considered a line break in this answer. There are many more line breaks chars out there.

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew for your comment, so which line break that i need to use, i think i know just `\n` is there others?

Comment: @YCF_L: See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with my code. I was reading in a file line by line and building the String, but didn't add a space at the end of each line. Therefore there were no actual line breaks to replace.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect case for Guava's [CharMatcher](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
String input = "and refreshingly direct\n\rwhen compared with the hand-waving of Swinburne.";
String output = CharMatcher.javaLetterOrDigit().or(CharMatcher.whitespace()).retainFrom(input);
```

Output will be:

```
and refreshingly direct
when compared with the handwaving of Swinburne
```